# Install ubuntuon UEFI mode on hp h8-1360t

Tags: uefi

This is a new computer that can only boot in UEFI mode. ( or at least I do not know how to switch to  normal BIOS mode). I am not able to install ubuntu 12.04.1 or ubuntu 12.10 using the livecd. The live CD does not boot properly. I get error message with subsequent kernel panic. It came with windows 7 preinstalled. bcdedit indicated that windows in UEFI mode. The problem is not solved even when I disconnect the windows disk.

Comment: Please burn a [Ubuntu-Secure-64bit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix) CD, and tell us if you can boot on it. If yes, please follow the 1st paragraph of [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

Comment: It was working with this cd, but it boots in legacy mode. I had to use boot repair subsequently. I was not able to find a 12.10 version. I had to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the exact same model(h8-1360t) which came with Windows 7 x64 and just installed Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop edition and writing here from it.

For the installation, I did not do anything specific, just downloaded the Ubuntu 12.10 ISO, burnt it on DVD, and then booted from the DVD and installed it.

Just something different from the original setup was that I used a HDD that was left over from other things, did a clean install to it, but disattached the other HDD's that I wasn't going to use in this setup.

I have not installed any special drivers to make the graphics better to have something like the wobbly dialogs so its just a normal install of Ubuntu 12.10.